# C# Array of instances with inheritance

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine

For an XNA engine I'm trying to make myself, I want an array/arraylist of instances that server as my game objects. If all of my game objects are parented to a GameObject class, what's a way I can do this?

Comment: Either your question is extremely simple (how do I create an array of objects of a certain type?) or I'm not correctly interpreting what it is you want.  Could you try to clarify your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
GameObject[] gameObjects = new GameObjects[100];
GameObject[0] = new GameObject();
GameObject[1] = new GameObject();
GameObject firstGameObject = gameObjects[0];
```

or

```
List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObjects>();
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject());
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject());
GameObject firstGameObject = gameObjects[0];
```

The first will allocate an array with 100 elements and assign the value of the first two elements. The second will create a list where two elements are added.

The `<>` indicates that `List<>` is a generic type where you can specify the type of the element stored in the list. This creates a *strongly typed* collection.

Compare that to using an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList gameObjects = new ArrayList();
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject());
gameObjects.Add(new GameObject());
GameObject firstGameObject = (GameObject) gameObjects[0];
```

The `ArrayList` class stores `Object` references and to access an item in the list you have to perform a cast. That is both tedious and error prone and you should always use `List<>` and not `ArrayList` unless you are developing .NET 1 code.

To learn more about generics you can study the [C# programming guide on generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm new to C#, and google couldn't really help me here: What do the <> mean?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have heard of generics.  Most the time if I need to create an array list of unknown object types I use a generic T.  If I know the data type I will simply use a List